# How do I write a CanCan ability with join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I'm using CanCan 1.6.10 with Rails 3.2.13

I'm setting up my Abilities for my Staff (rather than User) model. I have:

```
class Ability
    include CanCan::Ability
    def initialize(staff)
        if staff.role? :driver
            can :read, User.joins(:orders => {:delivery_slot => :driver}).where("driver_id = ?", staff.id)
```

I've tested the joins where in the console and it returns 7 records. When I test the ability it fails to return any:

```
User.accessible_by(Ability.new(Staff.find(7)))
```

The SQL from the last query .to_sql shows as:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (1=0)
```

whereas User.joins(:orders => {:delivery_slot => :driver}).where("driver_id = ?", 7) gives:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `orders` ON `orders`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` INNER JOIN `delivery_slots` ON `delivery_slots`.`id` = `orders`.`delivery_slot_id` INNER JOIN `staff` ON `staff`.`id` = `delivery_slots`.`driver_id` WHERE (driver_id = 7)
```

Comment: Posted a solution, can you pls check if that works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried a [hash of conditions](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities#hash-of-conditions) rather than having explicit joins?

```
can :read, User, :orders=>{:delivery_slot=>{:driver=>{:id => staff.id}}}
```

Comment: Thanks @RDX I think that works but it's returning duplicate results - is there a way to make it return only unique results?

Comment: I would rather not do it at CanCan level, and do it where we're using `accessible_by`. i.e. `User.accessible_by(Ability.new(Staff.find(7))).uniq`. Joins automatically create duplicate rows, and rather than trying to hit your head resolving this in CanCan, rather do it in the model. You could even create a helper method in your model which simply delegates to `accessible_by` and does the `uniq` automatically, like `def accessible_by_uniq(*args) do accessible_by(*args).uniq end`

Comment: Thanks, I created the helper method like you suggested in the User model but just to note for anyone following it should be a class method not instance method so 
    def self.accessible_by_uniq(*args)
        accessible_by(*args).uniq
    end